# Copying Bytes from Memory to char array then writing the bytes to a registry key via Driver C

Tags: c, windows, registry, driver

I am having an issue with my project where I am attempting to copy a structure from memory.

Copying the structure into a char array and writing the bytes in the char array to a registry key of type `REG_BINARY`

Here is the code so far, I am using `RtlCopyMemory` to achieve copying the bytes from memory:

```
   VOID ReadVirtualMem(ULONG32 address, PVOID buffer, SIZE_T size)
{
    PEPROCESS Process;
    if (NT_SUCCESS(PsLookupProcessByProcessId((HANDLE)ProcessID, &Process)))
    {
        KAPC_STATE  apc_state;
        KeStackAttachProcess(Process, &apc_state);

        if (MmIsAddressValid((PVOID)address) && MmIsAddressValid((PVOID)(address + size)))
        {
            RtlCopyMemory(buffer, (PVOID)address, size);
        }

        KeUnstackDetachProcess(&apc_state);
    }

   
}
```

The above code will take in a vew parameters, address of the location I need reading from, buffer aka output the bytes need to be stored in, and the amount of bytes I want copied.

So here is how I am obtaining the bytes from memory:

```
struct PlayerInformation {
    float Position;
    int Points;
    float Speed;
};

 struct PlayerInformation PlayerInfo;
 ReadVirtualMem(ReadAddress, &PlayerInfo, size);
```

I then cast this information to a `PVOID` data type so I can write this to the registry key like so:

```
PVOID Buffer;

memcpy(&Buffer, &PlayerInfo, sizeof(struct PlayerInfo));

status = WriteToKey(L"\\Registry\\Machine\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", L"Bytes", REG_BINARY, Buffer, size);


    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
        return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
```

The following above code works just fine for 8 bytes only. I believe this is due to `PVOID` only having a size of 8 bytes.

Here is my code for writing to the registry key:

```
NTSTATUS WriteToKey(PWSTR registry_path, PWSTR value_name, ULONG type, PVOID data, ULONG length)
{

    UNICODE_STRING valname;
    UNICODE_STRING keyname;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES attribs;
    HANDLE handle;
    NTSTATUS rc;
    ULONG result;

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&valname, registry_path);
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&keyname, value_name);

    InitializeObjectAttributes(&attribs, &valname, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE | OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE, NULL, NULL);

    rc = ZwCreateKey(&handle, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &attribs, 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_VOLATILE, &result);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(rc))
        return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;

    rc = ZwSetValueKey(handle, &keyname, 0, type, &data, length);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(rc))
        STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

My question is how would I be able to take the data copied from `RtlCopyMemory` into a structure, turn that structure into a `char` array and write this data to the registry key path.

In c++ its as easy as this:

```
unsigned char b[sizeof(PlayerInfo)];
    std::cout << "Size of structure: " << sizeof(PlayerInfo) << "\n\n";
    memcpy(b, &PlayerInfo, sizeof(PlayerInfo));

    HKEY handle;
    if (RegOpenKeyExA(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_WRITE, &handle) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        RegSetValueEx(handle, L"Bytes", 0, REG_BINARY, (BYTE*)&b, sizeof(b));
```

But C has no data type for BYTE* so I am just a bit confused on how I could go on about taking this C++ function, which works perfectly, and implementing it into C code to work the exact same way as the C++ function.

If you need any other details I will be more than gladly to give you the information.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: So I edited my function to accept the `PlayerInfo struct` as an argument and now all the data is read correctly.

Here is the updated code:

```
NTSTATUS WriteToBytes(PWSTR registry_path, PWSTR value_name, ULONG type, struct PlayerInfo data, ULONG length)
{

    UNICODE_STRING valname;
    UNICODE_STRING keyname;
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES attribs;
    HANDLE handle;
    NTSTATUS rc;
    ULONG result;

    RtlInitUnicodeString(&valname, registry_path);
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&keyname, value_name);

    InitializeObjectAttributes(&attribs, &valname, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE | OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE, NULL, NULL);

    rc = ZwCreateKey(&handle, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &attribs, 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_VOLATILE, &result);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(rc))
        return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;

    rc = ZwSetValueKey(handle, &keyname, 0, type, &data, length);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(rc))
        STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

This works well, no errors from what I can see. does anyone know why this works? And not passing a `void*` to the original write key function?

Comment: `PVOID Buffer;` seems to be an uninitialized pointer, i.e. pointing nowhere. It is not a buffer, but a pointer that **could** point to a buffer. `memcpy(&Buffer,...` takes the address of the pointer and changes the pointer value which may have the size of 8 bytes. You probably want something like `PVOID Buffer = (PVOID)&PlayerInfo;`

Comment: Your C++ function doesn't *"work perfectly"*, as you hope for. In C++ objects have a lifetime. Yours never starts. You'll have to learn about *placement `new`*.

Comment: @Bodo I edited the function, and I tried your method but it results in incorrect data. I've updated the function which works. Do you know why the updated function works and the original does not? Check the post above for the edited function.

Comment: @Ballers "I tried your method but it results in incorrect data" does not tell what exactly you tried. Without seeing the code that calls your functions it is difficult to tell what's going wrong. Passing a `void*` should work as well. You could simply pass the address and size of the structure without copying it to a separate buffer. The code `PVOID Buffer; memcpy(&Buffer, ...` is definitely wrong as I alread wrote.